# React file viewer not working with firebase storage links

Tags: javascript, reactjs, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

This works only for mp4 files which are uploaded for firebase storage

Here is my code sample:

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import FileViewer from "react-file-viewer";

import "./styles.css";

const file =
  "My_file_URL";
const type = "pdf";

const onError = (e) => {
  console.log(e, "error in file-viewer");
};

const props = {
  allowFullScreen: true,
  src:
    "xxxx"
};

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>React File Viewer Demo</h1>
      <h2>Displaying file with extension {type}</h2>
      <FileViewer fileType={type} filePath={file} onError={onError} />
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("fileviewer");
ReactDOM.render(<App />, root);
```

Comment: share any stackblitz

Comment: i have the same issue. did you find any solution?

Answer (score 0):

You are reusing [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/0uysf?file=/src/index.js) example.

If you give a look into the code you will see that the file const in line 8 is making reference to a local file, not an external one.

If you want to fetch a file from Firebase Storage and use it with this template you will need first to get it from the Storage bucket, and in order to be able to allow this you need to set [CORS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/web/download-files?hl=en#download_data_via_url)

What you cant to do is to create a file like this:

cors.json

```
[
 {
   "origin": ["*"],
   "method": ["GET"],
   "maxAgeSeconds": 3600
 }
]
```

and then from where you created run the following gsutil command:

```
gsutil cors set cors.json gs://lms-test-ce523.appspot.com
```

This can be easily done from Cloud Shell for example.

After this you will see your PDF

Also, don't forget to set proper access rules to your storage or you wont be able to access the file, I used [these](https://firebase.google.com/docs/rules/basics#mixed_public_and_private_access)